# Java equivalent of C++ encryption

Tags: java, c++, encryption, openssl

I have this following snippet from c++ code that is used for encryption:

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
const EVP_CIPHER * cipher = EVP_des_ede3_cbc();
unsigned char iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
unsigned char key[EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH];
String seed;

_config->get_value("crypto_seed", &seed); // uses the seed value from pimp config.

if (seed.is_empty())
{
    return false;
}

EVP_BytesToKey(cipher, EVP_sha1(),
        (unsigned char *) 0, // no salt
        reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(const_cast<char *>(seed.chars())), seed.length(),
        1, // hash passphrase just once.
        key, iv);

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
EVP_CipherInit_ex(&ctx, cipher, (ENGINE *) 0, key,
        iv,
        1); // encrypt
```

what s the equivalent of the c++ encryption in java?

I see there is `des` algorithm, then i see `sha1`.

This is related to openssl encryption. But not sure what is the equivalent. essentially i would like the same output as c++ code generates.

i m asking the what s the equivalent of `EVP_CIPHER_CTX` or what s the name of the encrytion being used here so i can take it from there.

**EDIT: not asking anyone to convert the code to java, just asking the corresponding package or class that would do the same.**

Comment: are you asking how to convert the above c++ into java?  Or is it a different question?

Comment: i m asking the what s the equivalent of `EVP_CIPHER_CTX` or what s the name of the encrytion being used here so i can take it from there.

Comment: @DarthVader - I have that stupid [hammer badge and I can't opt-out of it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323155). That means I can't cite a potential duplicate without closing the question. Please let me know if you object.

Comment: [OpenSSL 1.1.0c changed the digest algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39637388/608639) used in some internal components. Formerly, MD5 was used, and 1.1.0 switched to SHA256. Be careful the change is not affecting you in both `EVP_BytesToKey` and commands like `openssl enc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are converting from uses the openssl library. It carries out a triple-DES encryption using an Initial Vector. The first thing you need to understand is exactly what it's doing (and preferably why).

Unfortunately the openssl documentation isn't terribly thorough (see [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/evp.html)) ... though the O'Reilley book *Network Security with OpenSSL* is quite a bit better (it's a bit out of date, though).

Once you know what needs to be done, you shouldn't have much difficulty coding it in Java using the standard javax.crypto package.

Answer (score 2):

The trickiest part of this is the EVP_BytesToKey part, which has been recreated before.

[How to decrypt file in Java encrypted with openssl command using AES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783062/how-to-decrypt-an-encrypted-file-in-java-with-openssl-with-aes)

I've also got an object oriented version laying around here, if you are really not up to using that C-like code. For SHA-1, use SHA-1 instead of MD5...

As for the encryption, simply use `"DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding"` as algorithm name for your `Cipher.getInstance()` method and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The encryption being used is [Triple DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) with [cipher block chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29)

RSA page: [source](http://www.rsa.com/products/bsafe/documentation/mesuite21html/dev_guide/group__R__CR__IDS__CIPHER.html#aR_CR_ID_DES_EDE3_CBC)

> A cryptographic identifier which indicates a 3DES EDE CBC symmetric
>   cipher.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `EVP_CIPHER_CTX` is the “context” structure that's containing the encryption (akin to an object), but the actual cypher being used is `EVP_des_ede3_cbc` — which would be "des-ede3-cbc" with `OpenSSL.encrypt(…)` and friends

EDIT: To answer the question (“the corresponding package”), generally you should probably use `javax.crypto` or (probably “better” for most purposes) `bouncycastle` (http://www.bouncycastle.org/). But OpenSSL bindings do also exist — just awkward to use and deploy.

Comment: Thanks. i m also seeing `EVP_BytesToKey(cipher, EVP_sha1()`, so sha1 is also being used no?

Comment: It looks like it's using that for the key hashing, yes.  I'm afraid I'm not familiar with addressing it via C|C++, but the name seems clear :-)