# What is API in OpenSSL like Java DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding?

Tags: java, c, openssl, password-encryption, encryption-symmetric

I want to decrypt password which was encrypted by "DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" of javax.crypto.Cipher. I have  to use OpenSSL to decrypt the password. Which API in OpenSSL should I use?

I know API for DES3 is `DES_ede3_cbc_encrypt`, and want to know DES.

Answer (score 2):

You should also use `EVP_*` functions; and not functions like `DES_ede3_cbc_encrypt` (and friends). See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

To answer your question about DES symbols, you need to use `EVP_des_XXX`, where `XXX` is a mode of interest. I'm guessing you want `EVP_des_cbc`.

If you are working on a CentOS machine with the FIPS version of OpenSSL *and* FIPS mode is active, then you probably won't have access to any DES or 2-key 3DES algorithms (3-key 3DES should be available).

```
$ cd openssl
$ grep EVP_des include/openssl/evp.h
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_des_ecb(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_des_ede(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_des_ede3(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_des_ede_ecb(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_des_ede3_ecb(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_des_cfb64(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_des_cfb1(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_des_cfb8(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_des_ede_cfb64(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_des_ede3_cfb64(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_des_ede3_cfb1(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_des_ede3_cfb8(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_des_ofb(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_des_ede_ofb(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_des_ede3_ofb(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_des_cbc(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_des_ede_cbc(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_des_ede3_cbc(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_desx_cbc(void);
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_des_ede3_wrap(void);
```

---

Here are some references I keep cribbed away for OpenSSL and Java interop. Usually [`EVP_BytesToKey`](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:EVP_BytesToKey(3)) causes some issues.

- [Java AES 128 encrypting differently to openssl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21086103/608639)
- [Java equivalent of an OpenSSL AES CBC encryption](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32508961/608639)
- [How to decode a string encoded with openssl aes-128-cbc using java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31947256/608639)
- [Using Java to decrypt openssl aes-256-cbc using provided key and iv](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15594518/608639)
- [Java equivalent of C++ encryption](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12920740/608639)
- [How to use OpenSSL generated keys in Java?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/9600/29925)
- [Java openssl encryption / decryption key generation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34502705/608639)
- [Password to key function compatible with OpenSSL commands?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9488919)
- [How to decrypt file in Java encrypted with openssl command using AES?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11783062)

Comment: I use `DES_ncbc_encrypt`, and it works well in decrypting password which is encrypted by DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding of Java.