# InvalidKeyException using BouncyCastle and Unlimited JCE

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

I am attempting to encrypt/decrypt strings using AES-256-CBC and BouncyCastle. I have completed this for keys that are of length 16 bytes (128 bits) but **I am *required* to use a key of 128 bytes** (1024 bits).

I have read numerous suggestions on SO and found that the restricted policy files for the JVM I am using had not been installed. This, theoretically, *should* allow keys **greater** than 128 bits to be used. However, after installing the [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction policy files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) to my jdk (`1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security`) the issue remains.

The code I am using to encrypt a `String` is as follows:

```
String my_key =  "2bc7fa12d..." // String of length 128

Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

byte[] original = my_key.getBytes();
key = new SecretKeySpec(original, "AES");

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt.getBytes());
byte[] encryptedValue = Base64.encode(encrypted);

return new String(encryptedValue);
```

But after replacing the .jar's found in the Unlimited JCE download I still experience the error:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Key length not 128/192/256 bits.
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineInit(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at EncyrptionTest.encrypt(EncyrptionTest.java:58)
    at EncyrptionTest.main(EncyrptionTest.java:33)
```

Any advice or solutions to this issue would be greatly appreciated.

### Edit:

As requested, the code I am trying to port from Ruby into Java is as follows:

```
 WithCred.entials_for(:to_encrypt) do |c|
    attr_encrypted :my_key,
      :algorithm => 'aes-256-cbc',
      :key => c[:key]
  end
```

The gem it uses to encrypt (I believe) is [attr_encypted](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted). (I am afraid I know very little about Ruby)

Comment: It -should- work (been there myself), so are you really, really sure that the runtime you updated is the runtime that is used to run this stuff? I see it is going into a lib of a JDK, that is not the lib of a runtime. Generally it is easy to know you did it right because you have to overwrite existing files.

Comment: Secondary: are you sure AES supports such keys? If I quickly scan the wiki, I don't think so. I used a different encryption methodology myself. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard

Comment: @Gimby Not sure, I am porting some ruby code that is able to encrypt using a key of that length!? It is driving me bananas

Comment: Exception message explicitly lists key sizes supported by AES. 1024 bit keys could mean RSA or some other asymmetric cipher.

Comment: Please show us the ruby code, otherwise this question is going nowhere. Maybe you should learn something about cryptography before continuing?

Comment: @owlstead I have updated the question to provide the ruby code and the gem I believe it is using to encrypt.

Comment: Thank you @OlegEstekhin, but I am told it is _"definitely AES-256-CBC"_ (even though I am not convinced).

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform (the old, deprecated) MD5 key generation that is used in OpenSSL. Your Ruby code points to [this](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/encryptor/blob/master/lib/encryptor.rb)  source file. So the key is not really a key, it's a password which is converted to a key. Note that it uses MD5, doesn't use a salt and that it uses 2000 iterations by default.

Finally, it comes back to this:

```
EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cipher(ctx), digest, salt,
               (unsigned char *)RSTRING_PTR(vpass), RSTRING_LEN(vpass), iter, key, iv);
```

Of course you then need this OpenSSL proprietary key derivation option in Java. Fortunately, you wouldn't be the first one to require OpenSSL compatibility:

[How to decrypt file in Java encrypted with openssl command using AES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783062/how-to-decrypt-an-encrypted-file-in-java-with-openssl-with-aes)

I apologize in advance that I did not post my object oriented implementation instead in that answer :)

Comment: One thing has left me wandering though. `EVP_BytesToKey` actually returns the size of the hash generated. This is ignored in the Ruby code. The rest of the key bytes are simply generated by `unsigned char key[EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH]`. What will be in the bytes that are *not* generated by `EVP_BytesToKey`? I probably don't want to know...

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this seems to be quite confusing. Is there an `openssl` command on the terminal that can be used to get the password?

Comment: Does this code also require a password? I apologise, but I am not sure how to use the link you provided to help. Converting `my_string` to `byte[]` and putting it in the function you provided causes the error `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted`

Comment: Did you put in the same number of iterations/count? Oh, and you may want to put in keyLength as 16, the output size of MD5. Then copy the result into a new array of the right size (because of the issue above).

Comment: Note that you will get a BadPaddingException when the key is incorrect, or when one or two of the last blocks of ciphertext has become corrupted..