# BadPadding exception when trying to decrypt AES based encrypted text

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, aes, encryption-symmetric

**Problem Scenario:**   I am creating an encrypted file using OpenSSL AES-256-CBC mode in Ubuntu.

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -in avengers.txt -out avengers.enc 
test
test
File Content: avengersAssemble
avengers.enc file content: U2FsdGVkX194TyUFrb4gOn86XYaKjKP98YdOlQDJz+t/76mvVmNKl+NyKKUnYwYH

To Decrypt: openssl aes-256-cbc -a -d -in avengers.enc
```

Now I want to decrypt this encrypted file `avengers.enc` using java code i.e., I just store this file content and password (in this case test) to decrypt it.

**My Aim:** I want to decrypt using a password (symmetric encryption), encrypted from above command (128 or 192 or 256 cbc).

Please help.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783062/how-to-decrypt-file-in-java-encrypted-with-openssl-command-using-aes) code but its showing BadPadding exception. Please refer answer post by `@Maarten Bodewes` in the link.

Code which I found from the link:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;

public class OpenSSLDecryptor {
    private static final Charset ASCII = Charset.forName("ASCII");
    private static final int INDEX_KEY = 0;
    private static final int INDEX_IV = 1;
    private static final int ITERATIONS = 1;

    private static final int ARG_INDEX_FILENAME = 0;
    private static final int ARG_INDEX_PASSWORD = 1;

    private static final String file = 
    "D:\\Eclipse_Workspace\\Cryptography\\avengers.enc";
     private static final String password = "test";

    private static final int SALT_OFFSET = 8;
    private static final int SALT_SIZE = 8;
    private static final int CIPHERTEXT_OFFSET = SALT_OFFSET + SALT_SIZE;

    private static final int KEY_SIZE_BITS = 256;

    /**
     * Thanks go to Ola Bini for releasing this source on his blog.
     * The source was obtained from <a href="http://olabini.com/blog/tag/evp_bytestokey/">here</a> .
     */
    public static byte[][] EVP_BytesToKey(int key_len, int iv_len, MessageDigest md,
            byte[] salt, byte[] data, int count) {
        byte[][] both = new byte[2][];
        byte[] key = new byte[key_len];
        int key_ix = 0;
        byte[] iv = new byte[iv_len];
        int iv_ix = 0;
        both[0] = key;
        both[1] = iv;
        byte[] md_buf = null;
        int nkey = key_len;
        int niv = iv_len;
        int i = 0;
        if (data == null) {
            return both;
        }
        int addmd = 0;
        for (;;) {
            md.reset();
            if (addmd++ > 0) {
                md.update(md_buf);
            }
            md.update(data);
            if (null != salt) {
                md.update(salt, 0, 8);
            }
            md_buf = md.digest();
            for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {
                md.reset();
                md.update(md_buf);
                md_buf = md.digest();
            }
            i = 0;
            if (nkey > 0) {
                for (;;) {
                    if (nkey == 0)
                        break;
                    if (i == md_buf.length)
                        break;
                    key[key_ix++] = md_buf[i];
                    nkey--;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            if (niv > 0 && i != md_buf.length) {
                for (;;) {
                    if (niv == 0)
                        break;
                    if (i == md_buf.length)
                        break;
                    iv[iv_ix++] = md_buf[i];
                    niv--;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            if (nkey == 0 && niv == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < md_buf.length; i++) {
            md_buf[i] = 0;
        }
        return both;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // --- read base 64 encoded file ---

            //File f = new File(args[ARG_INDEX_FILENAME]);
            File f = new File(file);
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(f.toPath(), ASCII);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String line : lines) {
                sb.append(line.trim());
            }
            String dataBase64 = sb.toString();
            byte[] headerSaltAndCipherText = Base64.decode(dataBase64);

            // --- extract salt & encrypted ---

            // header is "Salted__", ASCII encoded, if salt is being used (the default)
            byte[] salt = Arrays.copyOfRange(
                    headerSaltAndCipherText, SALT_OFFSET, SALT_OFFSET + SALT_SIZE);
            byte[] encrypted = Arrays.copyOfRange(
                    headerSaltAndCipherText, CIPHERTEXT_OFFSET, headerSaltAndCipherText.length);

            // --- specify cipher and digest for EVP_BytesToKey method ---

            Cipher aesCBC = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

            // --- create key and IV  ---

            // the IV is useless, OpenSSL might as well have use zero's
            final byte[][] keyAndIV = EVP_BytesToKey(
                    KEY_SIZE_BITS / Byte.SIZE,
                    aesCBC.getBlockSize(),
                    md5,
                    salt,
                    password.getBytes(ASCII),
                    ITERATIONS); //args[ARG_INDEX_PASSWORD]
            SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyAndIV[INDEX_KEY], "AES");
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(keyAndIV[INDEX_IV]);

            // --- initialize cipher instance and decrypt ---

            aesCBC.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
            byte[] decrypted = aesCBC.doFinal(encrypted);

            String answer = new String(decrypted, ASCII);
            System.out.println(answer);
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            // AKA "something went wrong"
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Bad password, algorithm, mode or padding;" +
                    " no salt, wrong number of iterations or corrupted ciphertext.");
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Bad algorithm, mode or corrupted (resized) ciphertext.");
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }        
}
```

**Exception:**

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:991)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:847)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164)
    at symmetric.main(symmetric.java:146)
```

Comment: Prashant, could you try and replace the `"MD5"` string with `"SHA-256"` in the Java code and see if that works as well? I don't have 1.1 installed at the moment. It works perfectly if I use `-md sha256` in the command line of 1.0.

Comment: it workes with SHA-256

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OpenSSL` uses `EVP_BytesToKey` with uses Message Digest Algorithms like `md5`, `sha256`, etc. In the above code the function, `EVP_ByteToKey` has a MessageDigest parameter to which `MD5` is passed but MD5 was not added in the OpenSSL command while encryption. So below is the actual command to be used with the message digest algorithm i.e., MD5.

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -in avengers.txt -out avengers.enc -md md5
 openssl aes-256-cbc -a -d -in avengers.enc -md md5
```

To use any other message digest algorithm just pass that algoriyhm in     `MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");`  Refer [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html) under MessageDigest Algoritms. Also, have to pass `-md sha256` in command. Refer man page for openSSL

Comment: Cool, I'll note this in my other answer as well. If you could try it without `-md5` and with `"SHA-256"` you would safe me quite a lot of time :) Note that you can accept your own answer after a day or two. I'll refer to this answer from my other post.

Comment: Great, better to use SHA-256 if you don't need MD5 for backward compatibility. Note that MD5 has *not yet been broken* for this kind of functionality (key derivation).

Comment: Sure. Thanks for help and suggestion @MaartenBodewes

Comment: great job @PrashantJeetSingh

Answer (score 0):

openssl version

```
 LibreSSL 2.6.5
```

use your example with this jar file

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/b/Downloadbouncycastlejar.htm

exactly the same code except for this import

```
import bwmorg.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;
```

decrypt the same data with the same key

and it works perfectly

maybe its parameters issue

Comment: I tried above jar but no luck still getting same exception  
`javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:991)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:847)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164)
 at symmetric.main(symmetric.java:150)`

Comment: and you run the main with the correct order of arguments first the *.enc file and then the password?

Comment: yes did the same. Even tried storing file path and password in variable but no luck

Comment: did you try pass as first argument the absolute path to the file?

Comment: yes                                                                                                                
`private static final String file="D:\\Eclipse_Workspace\\Cryptography\\avengers.enc";
    private static final String password = "test";`

Comment: please attach your main function to the question

Comment: in the code you provide the argument gets from the main args here you posted hardcoded variables I want to see the code with the variables you mention here in the previous comment

Comment: I have updated the question with hardcoded parameters.

Comment: which openssl are you using ? (openssl version)

Comment: Open SSL version in ubuntu :  OpenSSL 1.1.0g

Comment: my avengers.enc file content is   `U2FsdGVkX194TyUFrb4gOn86XYaKjKP98YdOlQDJz+t/76mvVmNKl+NyKKUnYwYH`

Comment: Could you try to add `-md md5` to your command line interface? It states the hash function used for `EVP_BytesToKey` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @NaorTedgi Thanks for the help

Comment: Thank you guys as well, I'll add a warning to the other post. Of course, MD5 has been deprecated for a reason, I will try and see if I can make it work with SHA256 as well, which replaced MD5 as default if I'm not mistaken. I'll first have to install a 1.1 version though. This is a [change from 1.0 to 1.1 that I found on the internet](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/new-openssl-1-1-0-broken-compatibility-with-openssl-1-0-1-a-4175632653/).

Comment: i think it will be great if @PrashantJeetSingh  you will answer the question and explain what was the problem and how you solve it