# Decrypt with Java an encrypted word generated by OpenSsl

Tags: java, encryption, openssl

Inside Java code, I should decrypt a word encrypted as follows:

```
echo -n "secret" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -base64 -pass pass:password -md SHA1
```

I'm new to encryption, but I have found some sample how to encrypt/decrypt some AES/CBC with Java. But it requires Salt, Key and Iv.
I have found that OpenSsl is deriving these values from the "password", but I don't have found how to do the same in Java in order to decrypt the encrypted value.

Does someone knows how it works ? Are the Salt, Key and/or Iv stored in the ecrypted value ?
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: For AES-256-CBC, a salt is not something necessary. In your context, password is the key. Padded with zeros to 32 bytes. Because you didn't specified the IV, the default 16-byte zeros (`0x0000000000000000`) was used. That's all.

Comment: But when I'm using the "-p" ou "-P" option of openssl, I can see salt, Iv and Key values. I'm pretty sure that the salt is randomly generated by openssl and its value can be found in the result encrypted value (bytes 8 to 16).

Comment: My mains concern is how are Iv and Keys generated (derived) from the password ?

Comment: Does [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11783062/589259) answer your question?

Comment: Thanks Maarten, it looks like what I was looking for. I'm trying to implement it.

Comment: Well, openssl is probably enabled that by default; not sure. But as far as I know which I did wrote this in `awk`, IV has nothing to do with the password/keys. Just take a look at some java examples, and do something testings.

Comment: @Maarten: It is working fine. I can recover "secret" using your code. Thanks you very much.